# How to wait for redux state change and then render page in React

Tags: reactjs, authentication, redux

I am building simple authorization app using MERN stack, and after user logs in ( jwt token is being stored inside of a cookie ) he is redirected to home page and there in useEffect I dispatch action which will return true / false weather cookie is valid or not

```
   useEffect(()=>{
    dispatch(get_cookie_action());
   },[]);
```

above that in same home page I have this

```
 const cookie_data = useSelector( state => state.is_user_logged_in );
 const { cookie, loading } = cookie_data;
```

And in return I tried to form some logic but every time I redirect user to homepage he is immediately returned to login even if login is successful

```
    return (
        <>
       {
          cookie
          ?
           <h1>you are logged in !</h1>
          :
           <Redirect to="/login"/>
        }
       </>
       )
```

My initial state of cookie in redux reducers is "false" but it seams that react does not wait for cookie state change from false to true and immediately redirects user back to login ( I've also tried adding loading conditional but it does not work either )

Comment: please add more code to clarify the idea

Comment: Really this issue is that your state isn't truly a boolean because you want to capture the "initializing" state. I might recommend initializing `cookie` as `undefined` and check for that condition `if (cookie === undefined) { return "Loading..." }` before your true/false check

Answer (score 0):

Really this issue is that your state isn't truly a boolean because you want to capture the "initializing" state. I might recommend initializing `cookie` as `undefined` and check for that condition `if (cookie === undefined) { return "Loading..." }` before your true/false check

```js
if (cookie === undefined) {
  return <>Some loading indicator</>;
}

return cookie ? <h1>you are logged in !</h1> : <Redirect to="/login" />;
```

Comment: I've tried your solution but it does not work. After user logs in I redirect him to homepage but immediately he is returned to login page and cookie is false but when I return to homepage cookie is true and I can visit HomePage